# How Can I Analysis Devices In Kali Linux On My Network Without Wifi With Ethernet?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux on my vmware. And I wanna scan devices on my network. But I'm connecting to network with cat5 cable not with wifi. Is there any way for me to scan devices on my network without wifi? airmon-ng start eth0 command only finds itself. And I had error to connect internet with NAT on vmware so I'm connecting with bridge mod right now.

Answer (score 0):

Airmon-ng is for scanning wireless networks, without a wireless device, it isn’t going to be very useful.

Perhaps you are looking for tools to just analyze packets on your Ethernet network?  Look at tcpdump and wireshark to start.